# Display multiple way points in route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need help in Google Map V3
I want to display multiple points in the route.
Currently i have mentioned origin and destination, but how can I display all the points which I have in the waypoint (arrWaypoints) array?
Below is my code.

```
var origin = arrWaypoints[0];
var destination = arrWaypoints[1];
this.directions.route({
                    origin: origin,
                    destination: destination,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
                }, function(result, status) {
  ........
```

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there are no waypoints to display. If you have additional waypoints to include, the request would look something like this:

```
var origin = arrWaypoints[0];
var destination = arrWaypoints[arrWaypoints.length-1];
// Origin and destination don't need to be in the arrWaypoints anymore as they're listed separately in the request.
arrWaypoints.splice(arrWaypoints.length-1, 1);
arrWaypoints.splice(0, 1);
this.directions.route({
                origin: origin,
                destination: destination,
                waypoints: arrWaypoints,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
            }, function(result, status) {
  ........
```